# Incomprehensible string encoding python

Tags: python, pandas, string, python-3.6

I'm lost with string encoding, I've a CSV file of French cities, and certain cities have special caracters such : é ç and è so I got some a lot of strings like this `PÃ©ron, SaÃ´ne`  and `Ã‰tienne`, I tried two encodings utf-8 and latin-1 and no positive result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('villes_france.csv', encoding='latin-1')
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: Have you tried some of the other encodings from [the standard list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)?

Comment: Thank you for the list, I'll give a try of some of them.

Answer (score 1):

So basically problem here is that you do not know encoding used. In such case you might use [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) command line tool. Install it by doing `pip install chardet` in terminal then also in terminal cd to where your file is and do `chardetect villes_france.csv`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tool, I got this result : ``` Windows-1252 with confidence 0.6847391481371748 ``` I tried ```encoding = 'cp1252' ```, then ```encoding =  'windows-1252' ``` always the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know where this file came from? And, just to be careful, are you sure the problem isn't with your terminal displaying these characters?

Comment: No the problem isn't in my terminal I opened it with Excel and I got same result. The file source is https://sql.sh/736-base-donnees-villes-francaises